# how to return a promise when waiting for another promise before that

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

My view-model gives a call to a service A and that service A needs to call another service B. the B will return some value that is required by service A. But this seems not working.

Here is my code.

```
class BillingService {
rest: BaseRest;
baseUrl: string;
configurationService: ConfigurationService;
constructor() {
    this.configurationService = new ConfigurationService();
    this.rest = new BaseRest({ basePath: this.baseUrl, isExternal: true });
}
getClaimsSummary() {
    this.configurationService.getBillingConfiguration().then((data: BillingConfigurationModel) => {
        this.baseUrl = data.billingBaseUrl;
        return this.rest.GET<ClaimSummaryModel>("claims/GetClaimsHistory", {});
    });      
}}
```

getClaimsSummary is being called by view model

```
     this.billingService.getClaimsSummary().then((data: ClaimSummaryModel) => {
        //push to array
    });
```

getClaimsSummary depends on a value (baseUrl) that is returned by configurationService.getBillingConfiguration() . i am trying to understand how to return getClaimsSummary so that is it acceptable by viewmodel as a promise.

Please note that rest is using "bluebird" promise library.

Comment: yes it is typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`then()` already yields that promise. All you have to do is `return` it from your method:

```
getClaimsSummary() {
    return this.configurationService.getBillingConfiguration().then((data: BillingConfigurationModel) => {
//  ^^^^^^
        this.baseUrl = data.billingBaseUrl;
        return this.rest.GET<ClaimSummaryModel>("claims/GetClaimsHistory", {});
    });      
}
```

Comment: Thankyou it worked. i will accept the answer in one min.